# Auth0 AuthenticationAPI using AuthenticationRequest

Tags: c#, authentication, auth0, api-eveonline

I am trying to make a console app that consumes the EVE online API, it uses Auth0 verification for some API requests

Swagger details https://esi.tech.ccp.is/ui/
Auth0 url https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize?

i am currently trying to login systematically however i keep getting the error

> JsonReaderException Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I think i am doing the process wrong in the first place and that is just trying to pass the default json {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Some parameters are either missing or invalid"}

Could someone help me point out what i am missing please

```
private static void Main()
        {
            var t = Task.Run(() => LoginAsync());
            t.Wait();
        }

private static async Task LoginAsync()
        {
            const string URL = "https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize?";
            AuthenticationApiClient client = new AuthenticationApiClient(new Uri(URL));

        var cred = new Auth0.AuthenticationApi.Models.AuthenticationRequest
        {
            ClientId = "abcdef",
            Username = "UN",
            Password = "PW",
            Scope = "esi-markets.structure_markets.v1",
            Connection = "Username-Password-Authentication"
        
        };
        Auth0.AuthenticationApi.Models.AuthenticationResponse response = await client.AuthenticateAsync(cred);            
    }
```

I am trying to retrieve the auth token so that I can do further requests with it. How can it be done?

Comment: Set the accept header to application/json.

Comment: how do i make the header in auth0. there is no client.header or client.accept in AuthenticationApiClient?

Comment: I tried doing as suggested with the following

Comment: I tried doing this by adding a custom handler

    AuthenticationApiClient client = new AuthenticationApiClient(new Uri(URL), new CustomMessageHandler());

    public class CustomMessageHandler : HttpClientHandler
        {
            protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

still no success.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an access token using [implicit grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/implicit-grant) which is not correct. Implicit grant should be executed only in the browser (Javascript client). For non interactive client, you can implement [Client credentials grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/client-credentials) or [resource owner password grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant) to get the access token. At first, create a [Machine to Machine client](https://auth0.com/docs/applications/machine-to-machine) and use that client credentials for token. The following code implements client credentials grant.

```
 class Program
    {
        private static string accessToken;
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await ClientCredentialsFlow();
        }

        protected static async Task ClientCredentialsFlow()
        {
            var body = new Model
            {
                grant_type = "client_credentials",
                client_id = "[client id]",
                client_secret = "[client secret]",
                audience = "[API Identifier]"
            };
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
                var stringContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var res = await client.PostAsync("https://[domain].auth0.com/oauth/token", stringContent);
                var responseBody = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var deserilizeBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponseModel>(responseBody);
                accessToken = deserilizeBody.access_token;
                Console.WriteLine(accessToken);

            }
        }

        internal class Model
        {

            public string grant_type { get; set; }
            public string client_id { get; set; }
            public string client_secret { get; set; }
            public string audience { get; set; }
        }

        internal class AuthResponseModel
        {
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            public string scopes { get; set; }
            public string expires_in { get; set; }
            public string token_type { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

To implement resource owner password grant, look at the following doc. 
https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant